# Run a bash script through CGI on closing of browser window

Tags: javascript, cgi

I have Apache tomcat server(8) installed on linux machine
I want to run the script placed under CGI  whenever user close the browser window.
It's like clean script. which should be executed on browser close.

I know how to execute the cgi script from browser. But here i want to execute on closing of browser window.

Also the html code for closing browser window is changing every time.i.e i will not add the event handler on that page